# Is there way I can show value in textbox in my jsp page even if object is null?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am having chicken and egg situation:
i have 2 servlets and i want the di object to show through search, not by display servlet

Question:

1. **Is there way I can show the refID in my jsp page even if object is
   empty?** currently,  In my code, i added default query just to fill the "dmsearch" so Jsp don't give
   error`(SearchDataManagerController.searchDMData(0, 0, 0);)`.
2. Or any other solution so my search value should show even display servlet is loaded?

Problem:
On page load, i don't necessarily want to show refId data (servlet 1). if it displays its ok BUT when i click on Search, it should display the data(servlet 2). it displays searched value in textbox but Servlet 1 loads and reset the value back.

Using "Get" in jsp

Code:

```
<%  DataManager di = (DataManager) session.getAttribute("dmsearch");    %>
<input type="text" name="refId" id="refId" value ="<%= di.getiD() %>">

//Servlet display: 1:
DataManager dm;
        String buttonClickStatus = request.getParameter("buttonClickStatus");
        dm = SearchDataManagerController.searchDMData(0, 0, 0);
        session.setAttribute("dmsearch", dm);

//Servlet search: 2:
        dm = SearchDataManagerController.searchDMData(driverid, textid, weekid);
        session.setAttribute("dmsearch", dm);
```

[image]
please help
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will help you but there is the Expression Language you can read about it, it's so usefull to avoid java code in jsp pages. 
You can try this but I'm not sure if this is what you want:

```
<input type="text" name="refId" id="refId" value ="${ empty di ? 1 : di.getId()}">
```

Comment: Thank you, let me try

Comment: no, it just litteral print the "${ empty di ? 1 : di.getId()}">            into the textbox

Comment: I think the EL is not working for you try adding this on the top of your jsp page `<%@ page isELIgnored="false" %>`

Comment: Ah ok. make sense. let me try. Thank you

Comment: It was messing up in JSP side, i added pretty much same condition in servlet side(see answer). Thank you for help

Comment: So you got what you needed?

Comment: Yes, now having another issue.             https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62377237/name-tag-in-html-refreshes-the-textbox-value

Comment: Can you accept the answer on this question right here? it will be nice :)

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

```
DataManager dm = new DataManager();
int textid=0;
int driverid=0;
int weekid=0;
if(request.getParameter("textid")!=null) {
    textid= Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("textid"));
}
if(request.getParameter("driverid")!=null) {
    driverid= Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("driverid"));
}
if(request.getParameter("weekid")!=null) {
     weekid= Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("weekid"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Solution:

DataManager dm = new DataManager();
int textid=0;
int driverid=0;
int weekid=0;
if(request.getParameter("textid")!=null) {
    textid= Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("textid"));
}
if(request.getParameter("driverid")!=null) {
    driverid= Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("driverid"));
}
if(request.getParameter("weekid")!=null) {
     weekid= Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("weekid"));
}
```